# Modify table content with a sql query

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a db table like this:

```
------------------------------------
--Col1---Col2---Col3---Col4---Col5--
|  A   |  B   |   C  |  D   |  -10  | 
|  A   |  B   |   C  |  D   |  -10  |
|  A   |  B   |   C  |  D   |  30   |
|  D   |  F   |   C  |  D   |  400  |
|  X   |  F   |   C  |  D   |  250  |
|  A   |  B   |   C  |  D   |  75   |
```

I want to transform this table into this form:

```
------------------------------------
--Col1---Col2---Col3---Col4---Col5--
|  A   |  B   |   C  |  D   |  85   | 
|  D   |  F   |   C  |  D   |  400  |
|  X   |  F   |   C  |  D   |  250  |
```

As you see Col5 value is the sum of repeated Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 values. How can I do that with a sql query or pl/sql script?

Comment: use ```GROUP BY``` and ```SUM``` should do the trick. But from your info it is unclear if Col1-4 are changing and if so how

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,SUM(Col5) as Col5
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
```

Since `SUM` is an aggregate function, you need to `GROUP BY` all other selected values.

Result:

```
COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4    COL5
A       B       C       D       85
D       F       C       D       400
X       F       C       D       250
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68370/1).

Read more about `SUM` [**here**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx).